# Javascript : add/remove json element in json object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to modify my JSON Object by add/remove Json element. Here is my JSON Object,

```
var candidate = {  
   "name":"lokesh",
   "age":26,
   "skills":[  
      "Java",
      "Node Js",
      "Javascript"
   ]
};
```

I need to remove the element "skills" and output should be like,

```
{  
   "name":"lokesh",
   "age":26
}
```

And I again I need to add the element "skills" as string and the output should be like,

```
{  
   "name":"lokesh",
   "age":26,
   "skills":"javascript"
}
```

Please help,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In JS , You can directly access candidate variable and assign only javascript to it . candidate.skills = "javascript"

Comment: Add the code you have written so far and which problem are you facing. You must demonstrate some research was done before asking. See [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 10):

Other ways it can be achieved.

For Adding:

```
candidate["skills"] = "javascript";
```

For Deleting:

```
var skill = "javascript";
delete candidate[skill];
```

or

```
delete candidate.skills;
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing a property of an object can be done by using the delete keyword:

```
candidate.delete("skills");
```

OR

```
   delete candidate["skills"];
```

To add a property to an existing object in JS you could do the following.

```
candidate["skills"] = "javscript";
```

OR

```
candidate.skills = "javscript";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 1):

For removing:

[How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

For adding, just set the new value for that property.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly assign "javscript" to "skills" key.

```
var candidate = {  
   "name":"lokesh",
   "age":26,
   "skills":[  
      "Java",
      "Node Js",
      "Javascript"
   ]
};
```

You can directly do this.

```
candidate.skills = "javascript";
```

Or you can delete the "skills" key and add it again.

e.g.

```
delete candidate["skills"];

candidate["skills"] = "javascript";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use delete method to delete members of an object.

```
delete candidate.skills;
```

Note: You cannot delete objects or functions in the global scope with **delete** keyword. However you can delete a function which is a member of an object.

Answer (score 0):

For removing:

```
candidate.delete("skills");
```

For adding:

```
candidate.skills = "javscript"
```

Comment: `delete candidate.skills;`

Comment: Your code has syntax error. @RolandStarke proposed the correction.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of coude should do it:

```
var candidate = {  
   "name":"lokesh",
   "age":26,
   "skills":[  
      "Java",
      "Node Js",
      "Javascript"
   ]
};

delete candidate.skills;
console.log(candidate);
candidate["skills"] = "javascript";
console.log(candidate);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is your json object

```
var candidate = {  
       "name":"lokesh",
       "age":26,
       "skills":[  
          "Java",
          "Node Js",
          "Javascript"
       ]
    };
```

to read any prop you can call like:

```
var name = candidate.name; or candidate[0].name
var age = candidate.age; or candidate[0].age;
var skills = candidate.skills; or candidate[0].skills;
```

to write any of prop:
candidate.name = 'moaz';
candidate.age = 35;

remove skills value:

```
candidate.skills = null; or candidate.skills = '';
```

here skills is list of json if I use as string value or list of string:

```
candidate.skills = 'javasccript'; //Use skills as string value
candidate.skills.push('javascript'); //Use skills as list of string
```

to read skills:

```
for (var i = 0; i < candidate.skills.length; i++) {
   var skill = candidate.skills[i];
}
```

Comment: delete candidate.skills; will remove prop with value